# static const pointer to global volatile

Tags: c, pointers, static, const-pointer

How can I declare a static const pointer to global volatile?

I have this so far, but I'm not sure it's correct:

```
// a.c
volatile bool flag_it_1;
volatile bool flag_it_2;

// a.h
extern volatile bool flag_it_1;
extern volatile bool flag_it_2;

// b.c
#include "a.h"
static volatile bool *const flag_it_ptr = &flag_it_1;
```

**Edit:**
I use it like this:

```
if (*flag_it_ptr) {
        // work
        *flag_it_ptr = false;
}
```

For those wondering why I am using that pointer:
I may change the variable I'm using from compilation to compilation, and didn't want to be changing names across the whole file, so this way I change it once.  More or less like a macro or a const global variable.

Is this correct?

**Edit:**
It compiled on gcc

Comment: Did you try it? Even if it's not conclusive, if the compiler allows it then it's good hint that it probably is okay.

Comment: The compiler allowed it. However, in other cases, I screwed some times assuming that if it compiled it would do what I supposed it would do.

Comment: You could also define an inline "getter" in the `a.h` something like `bool isFlag(void) { return flag_it_1;}`, anyway according to `const`, you are not going to modify it....

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: `const` is there so that the pointer is not modified. However the volatile flag IS going to be modified in "b.c". In fact, I do: `*flag_it_ptr = false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That construct just declares the const pointer to the not const object. So you are allowed to change the referenced object but not the pointer itself.

```
 #define flag_it_ptr flag_it_1
```

will do the job without the pointers. I think you over complicate the simple things.

Comment: I thought of that, but I don't feel very comfortable with it.  Don't really know why, but the pointer seems safer to me.

Comment: It does not give you safety of any kind

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about it, and the only reason I've found to keep the pointer is so that I remember that it is a `volatile bool` which I could forget if I used a macro.